# How to encrypt big files with php and decrypt over commandline?

Tags: php, linux, encryption, cryptography, mcrypt

I'm writing a small script in PHP to backup my files. Before I transfer the files from the server I want to encrypt them.

I did that in previous versions of my script by using exec() and OpenSSL on my Linuxserver. Now I'm looking for a native PHP-Function to do this job, mainly for better error handling.

The thing is that my files may get big (like 20gb). Furthermore it's a must that I can use a command on my shell to decrypt the file again.

Does anyone know how to encrypt big files in PHP and then decrypt on the commandline?

I'm now using PHP's mcrypt functions to encrypt:

```
// IV:
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_RAND);

// Create new random Key:
$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);

// Encrypt:
$fileStream = fopen($file, "r");
$encFileStream = fopen($file . ".enc.data", "w");

$opts = [
    'iv'   => $iv,
    'key'  => $key,
    'mode' => 'cbc'
];
stream_filter_append($encFileStream, 'mcrypt.rijndael-256', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
stream_copy_to_stream($fileStream, $encFileStream);

fclose($fileStream);
fclose($encFileStream);

// Encrypt random generated key and save it:
$encryptedKey = null;
openssl_public_encrypt($key, $encryptedKey, $publickey);
file_put_contents($file . ".enc.key", $encryptedKey);

// Save Initial Vetor:
file_put_contents($file . ".enc.iv", $iv);

// Delete unencrypted file:
unlink($file);
```

Now to decrypt on the linux commandline I tried to use mcrypt as well. But the big problem I have with that is that I have no idea how to add the IV to `mdecrypt`. My command I have so far is:

```
mdecrypt --decrypt -m CBC -f key.key archive_hallo.tar.gz.enc.data
```

Which of course does not work because the IV is missing. So, **does anyone know how to add the IV to my mdecrypt command**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mdecrypt` CLI tool from  mcrypt_2.6.8 debian package [expects the specific file format with header](http://sources.debian.net/src/mcrypt/2.6.8-1.3/src/extra.c?hl=222#L168). Search for `write_file_head` function, it shows first 3 bytes of the mcrypt/mdecrypt tool format:

```
buf[0] = '\0';
buf[1] = 'm';
buf[2] = '\3';
```

Header should have special bit set, and the IV embedded into the file. It will be read [here, in `decrypt_general` function](http://sources.debian.net/src/mcrypt/2.6.8-1.3/src/classic.c?hl=73#L563):

```
if (_mcrypt_iv_is_needed(td, mode, noiv) != 0) {
   IV = read_iv(FROMF, mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size(td));
} else {
   IV = _mcrypt_calloc(1, mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size(td));
}
```

and `read_iv` is defined in [extra.c](http://sources.debian.net/src/mcrypt/2.6.8-1.3/src/extra.c?hl=283#L283) as:

```
void *read_iv(FILE * fstream, int ivsize)
{
char *IV;
     ... // malloc 
fread(IV, 1, ivsize, fstream);
    return IV;
}
```

So, just check first N bytes of encrypted file (you can post them here after `hexdump -C`) and check for mcrypt header (0x00 'm' 0x03) and for your IV. If yes - then `mdecrypt` tool should get IV from file. If not - there is no support for setting IV via command-line in `mdecrypt`, but you can hack into sources, add new option for iv, then modify `decrypt_general` to read iv from option.

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering. If I do hexdump the first line is: `00000000  76 80 ee 78 05 07 03 36  72 a7 62 46 78 95 11 91  |v.îx...6r§bFx...|`. How can I find out if the second byte is an 'm'?

Comment: 'm' is 0x6d - use www.asciitable.com. So, your output from PHP mcrypt is not in format of `mdecrypt` utility. You should add right header and fill IV into it; OR you can hack into `mdecrypt` utility and add IV command-line option. Or you can write small php script to decrypt file using php functions, and then run this php script from the bash as `php script.php` or smth like.

Comment: Okey, thank you very much. Gonna try to add the header and the IV to the file. Is there a Documentation of how the header has to be? Or do I have to figure it out by reading the code? Thank you again!

Comment: I don't get it. Can you help me? Here is how I tried it (see line 13, 14): https://gist.github.com/DeDu/3804940cffc19db4aedf

Comment: Matthias, you can try to encrypt known file with command-line `mcrypt` and compare results with your script (there is `--noiv` option to set IV to all zeroes). Don't know about exact format (reading sources may help here).

Comment: Wasn't able to do it, but thank you anyway @osgx . I just use my own script to decrypt... If anyone else was successful, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of PHP can execute an individual file from the command line, you can always create a PHP command-line program to perform the decryption. Depending on your security settings, you may need to execute PHP through a shell program (`php -q decrypt.php` in the shell file) rather than directly (`#!/usr/bin/php/cli/php` or somesuch).

Comment: That's the solution I use at the moment. But I like to be able to decrypt the files of my backup without needing my script. Thank you anyway!

Comment: So how do you think some command-line programs are implemented :)? Take a look at Puppet, for instance -- it is in Ruby. With the proper magic incantation at the front (`#!/usr/bin/perl` for example), you need never think about what language the command is actually implemented in.

Comment: Yes, I know how a shebang works. The goal was to not rely on my script to decrypt my backups. I wanted to encrypt with the PHP-Encryption methods, and then when I need my backup I want to be able to use mdecrypt (because it's more likely that I will have that handy when). Thanks for your help, but my problem has nothing to do with the shebang ;-)